# 16.04 How to get Chrome to obey /etc/hosts?

Tags: google-chrome, dns

On my Ubuntu 16.04, Firefox obeys `/etc/hosts` but chrome and chromium don't. How can I get Chrome to obey `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: out of curiosity: Why?

Comment: For web development with wordpress, when I want to develop locally as wordpress is poorly designed to deal with url changes

Comment: Chrome does obey /etc/hosts in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

See a [similar question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/723703/why-is-chromium-bypassing-etc-hosts-and-dnsmasq). Basically, to make Chromium and Chrome obey `/etc/hosts` you should disable the setting "*predict network actions to improve page load performance*".

Comment: Yes I tried that but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome [data saver plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-saver/pfmgfdlgomnbgkofeojodiodmgpgmkac) and it is switched on, chrome won't take host file settings into account. Try switching it off and it will work as expected.